# Displaying direction between two location without GPS/ Mapkit

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a blueprint say for example a blueprint for a mall.

Now i want to show the direction between the source and destination to the client.
I don't have latitude and longitude.So for example if the user is at NIKE store in a mall and wants to go to ADIDAS store how do i graphically show him the direction from NIKE->ADIDAS.

Something like this (Almost the same thing they have done) :

http://www.mobilefringe.com/products/square-one-shopping-center-app-for-iphone-and-android/

Please help and guide me as to how should i proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think that is possible with manually setting you graphically. Here lost's of question with this task that.

- how did you get overall areas from location to destination. how much distance?
- without Lat Long how to know where is that particular place.
- without gps/map how did you know that between destination or your location where is street and where is turn.? or so on many issue for doing this manually.

So i strongly said that this is not possible manually. without use of gps/map

Comment: Before i answer you question, id like if you could see a link i have specified in my question.What i want is almost the same thing they have done and they haven't used any GPS, so i believe if they can do it its possible

Comment: ok then al the very best :) and if that does that means that store lat long or other data store manually database and set all structure

Comment: Additionally we have a blueprint which would give us the details like for example say NIKE is on the First floor and ADIDAS on second…. in short we know the positions its just we need to show it to the user graphically

Comment: If you have the shop positions and the data on the (walkable)"paths", then just use path finding to find the route from shop A to shop B.

Comment: Anything would do apart from map kit… if you could elaborate a bit more… @radical

Answer (score 0):

At first you will have to get latitude and longitude from the address. Once you get this, below link will be usefull to you which also contains sample code:

http://iosrider.wordpress.com/2012/05/09/draw-route-between-two-location/

Also to get lat long from address you can use following code:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) geoCodeUsingAddress:(NSString *)address
{
    double latitude = 0, longitude = 0;
    NSString *esc_addr =  [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *req = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", esc_addr];
    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:req] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    if (result) {
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:result];
        if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lat\" :" intoString:nil]) {
            [scanner scanDouble:&latitude];
            if ([scanner scanUpToString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil] && [scanner scanString:@"\"lng\" :" intoString:nil]) {
                [scanner scanDouble:&longitude];
            }
        }
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center;
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;
}
```

Comment: I am afraid but we won't be dealing with the Latitude and Longitude.
And the catch is we have no gps involved. If you could see the link specified in the question you would get a clear picture.Almost the same thing is required.